# Taking screenshot in a Background Service

Tags: java, android, kotlin, background-service

I am trying to make a bubble app that takes screenshot of other apps.

I found this project [link](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/FINAL/MediaProjection/andshooter) with a media projection sample but the images are not been saved to the device.

is there a way i can save this image to the device or is there any other way i can take a screenshot with my app in a background service.

Comment: "but the images are not been saved to the device" -- the sample [has code to save the images](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/FINAL/MediaProjection/andshooter/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/andshooter/ScreenshotService.java#L127-L155). [This slightly older edition of the sample](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/v8.1/MediaProjection/andshooter/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/andshooter/ScreenshotService.java) is covered in detail in [this free older edition of one of my books](https://commonsware.com/Android/Android-8.1-CC.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for the question, this is something I should also be looking for. But with this model can we perform screen capture automatically after x seconds without the need of a button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked the link and I think there's a way to save the file taken from screenshot.

From `ImageTransmogrifier` class

```
@Override
  public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
    final Image image=imageReader.acquireLatestImage();

    if (image!=null) {
      Image.Plane[] planes=image.getPlanes();
      ByteBuffer buffer=planes[0].getBuffer();
      int pixelStride=planes[0].getPixelStride();
      int rowStride=planes[0].getRowStride();
      int rowPadding=rowStride - pixelStride * width;
      int bitmapWidth=width + rowPadding / pixelStride;

      if (latestBitmap == null ||
          latestBitmap.getWidth() != bitmapWidth ||
          latestBitmap.getHeight() != height) {
        if (latestBitmap != null) {
          latestBitmap.recycle();
        }

        latestBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapWidth,
            height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
      }

      latestBitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);
      image.close();

      ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      Bitmap cropped=Bitmap.createBitmap(latestBitmap, 0, 0,
        width, height);

      cropped.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);

      byte[] newPng=baos.toByteArray();

      svc.processImage(newPng);
    }
  }
```

as you can notice there's a `latestBitmap` object there, from here you can actually save this bitmap to whatever place you want to save.

E.g. you can refer to this link https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-save-bitmap-to-gallery/ to save it on your Gallery :)

Comment: how can i call `start record` from `BroadcastReceiver` class in background?